# Not able to get all values from a table with selenium chrome webdriver using python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, chrome

I want to know the way to collect all the information from a table from a web page. 
At the moment I am able to get only the records which are visible in UI. (18 rows). However there are 96 rows in the table and i need to either scroll in the table frame or need some script to get all the data from the table. 
please help. here's my UI page https://wbes.wrldc.in/ReportNetSchedule/GetNetScheduleIndex

Comment: Also you have option to download csv and excel for that page , just download and parse it

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint `https://wbes.wrldc.in/ReportNetSchedule/GetNetScheduleSummary` returns a HTML with JS code that contains the data you are looking for.

You can either parse this HTML or separate the data from the HTML itself, creating a new endpoint for it (you should, because this is ugly JS). Then you can fetch the data with a simple cURL call.

[image]

Comment: I am able to get the data. however not completely as the table is a web element and i am getting the data only which is shown in UI. I want to scroll or get the complete data from the table.